# Get server's answer after saving model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I use Ember data with a node js server; the model looks very simple:

```
Gmcontrolpanel.Product = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
description: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Once the node server receives the product.save(), it persists the record in the mysql db, managing the record ID and answers like this:

```
{
  product
      {
         id: 1,
         name: "aaa",
         description "bbb"
      }
}
```

I need to get the id of the server's response (not the promise returned by save().then(), where id is null); how can i get it?

Update:

The node server, using express:

```
GMserver.post('/products', function (req, res) {
    rootName = "product";
    queryString = 'INSERT INTO products (id, name, descriptions ) VALUES ( '+ counters.prodcuts +', "' + req.body.product.name + '", "' + req.body.product.description + '")';
    executeQuery(req, res, queryString);
    responseToPost(counters.products, req.body.product, rootName, res);

    counters.products++;
});

function executeQuery (req, res, querystring) {
    connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields){
        if (err) throw err;   
    });
}

function responseToPost (id, data, rootName, res) {
    var result = new Object();
    result[rootName] = new Object();
    var i = 0;
    var answer;

    result[rootName].id = id;
    for(var key in data) 
    { 
        result[rootName][key] = data[key];
    }

    answer = JSON.stringify(result, null, '\t');

    console.log(answer);
    res.send(answer);
}
```

I can see by the log of answer here, that answer is the one written above;
I tried to change responseToPost to send always a static value like this:

```
result[rootName][key] = 'aaa';
```

but in Ember, doing

```
product.save().then(function(savedProduct) {
    console.log(savedProduct.get('name'));
}
```

i get the sumbmitted value of name, not 'aaa' as I expected...

Second Update:
doing in Ember

```
product.save().then(function(savedProduct) {
    console.log(savedProduct);
}
```

to see what savedProduct is, in Chrome i see the result of the log:

```
Class {id: null, store: Class, container: Container, currentState: (...), errors: Class…}
 __ember1395755543625: "ember548"
 __ember1395755543625_meta: Object
 __nextSuper: undefined
 _attributes: Object
 _changesToSync: Object
 _data: Object
     __ember1395755543625_meta: Meta
     _super: function superFunction(){
     name: "asdf"
     description: "asdfa"
    __proto__: Object
_deferredTriggers: Array[0]
_inFlightAttributes: Object
_relationships: Object
_suspendedRelationships: false
_updatingRecordArraysLater: false
container: Container
currentState: (...)
get currentState: function () {
set currentState: function (value) {
data: (...)
errors: Class
id: null
isError: false
store: Class
toString: function () { return ret; }
__proto__: Object
```

where "asdf" and "asdfa" are the values i typed in the insert form on the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The record should be updated if that's the JSON returned.

```
product.save().then(function(record){ //record is the same as product here
  console.log(record.get('id'));
});
```

Comment: doing as you suggested, the log says: null

Comment: Can you show what chrome/browser is showing the response is?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the network response from the save, I know above you said what the answer from node is, I'm just curious what the response chrome is seeing.

Comment: Ah ok, well the network resonse says: product 127.0.0.1, method POST, status 200 OK, type text/html, size 451 B content 123 B, time 51 ms latency 50 ms

Comment: if I remove the sending of response from the node server, the network response in Chrome is showing status (failed) net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, and the function in save().then() is not executed... So it seems it should work... But i can't get the returned data...

Comment: Still send the response, but I wouldn't expect type text/html?  I would expect application/json and the response to be `{ product : { id: 1, name: "aaa", description: "bbb" } }`, note the colon after product and description.  I'm assuming you typed that portion in since it isn't valid json.

Comment: yes, the missing colon is a typo I made writing here... The server response is exactly as you wrote except that product is quoted ("product"), but i think this is not a problem (for the find request it works)... Maybe i should change the type... I'll try and I'll let you know...

Comment: No, even after setting content type (now in Chrome I can see that the network request's type is application/json), the log is still saying the submitted value and not the response from the server... If I do console.log record.get('name') i get the submitted value of name and not 'aaa' that the server is returning now; if i try record.get('id') it says null

Comment: agreed, it should make no difference, I'm showing it as working, are you using an older version of ember data? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/311/edit

Comment: Ok, thank you for this useful example... The only difference is that my is an insert form, not an edit form; so i don't have the model hook in the route since I want the fields empty; in the save action on the controller i just do: var data = this.getProperties('name', 'description');
var product = this.store.createRecord('Product', data);    and then product.save()           maybe this is not the right way of doing things...

Comment: `product` should be lower case in that create record.

Comment: Well you saved my project and simplified my life! Thank you for the patience, for the example!